# Height page - Div structure

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get my page to occupy 100% of the screen, with a footer, which needs to always be on the bottom of the page.

The div's should expand when the page resizes, with the right background color.

The bugs I have at the moment are : 
- Footer stays at bottom of the screen not of the page.
- div (menu) is bigger than the div (content)
- the div doesn't resize properly

Here's my code:

**Div stucture**

```
<div id="container"><br />
   <div id="header">CMS</div>

   <div id="menu"><?php include ('includes/menu.php');?></div>
   <div id="content">
      <?php include $include_page?>
   </div>

   <div id="footer">CMS</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    color: #0b0b0b;
    background-color: #696060;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12.5px;  
}

#container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-left: 1px solid #8f8f8f;
    border-right: 1px solid #8f8f8f;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a31f00;
    color: #fcfcfc;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu {
    width: 210px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    width: 750px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;    
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #a31f00;
    color: #fcfcfc;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Please format this into a readable format.

Comment: When writing questions and answers, StackOverflow shows you a preview pane in which you can see what your post will look like. Please ensure that it is formatted properly before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be thinking about a *sticky footer*. A sticky footer sticks to the bottom of the page when there isn't enough content to push it down, but when the content starts overflowing the page, it goes along with it.

To make one, you basically want to wrap everything which is not the footer within a `<div>` tag, like so:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header">
    ...
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <!-- All you page content goes here -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  I am a footer.
</div>
```

Now, for the magic CSS:

```
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap
{
  min-height: 100%;
}

#main
{
  overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px; /* must be same height as the footer */
}  

#footer
{
  position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear: both;
} 

/* Opera Fix */
body:before
{
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    margin-top: -32767px;/
}
```

And on your HTML page you will need this conditional style for IE6 and earlier and for IE8 (`!IE7` means not 7, but all others):

```
<head>
  ...
  <!--[if !IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css">
    #wrap
    {
      display: table;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
  ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try putting the content div inside the menu div. That way the menu is always the height of it's content, while content div can push the menu - and it's content down where applicable. Remove the height 100%.

Why pos:abs on the footer?  Have you tried relative?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read this for aligning your footer at the bottom of the screen, regardless of content above; http://www.zymic.com/tutorials/html/effective-footers/