# Why doesn't min-height not work on my page?

Tags: html, background-image, css

I have a gradient applied to the background of the body element. Then I have a container (right after body) that has a background .png image applied to it. The gradient always expands to at least 100% window height but the container (#body2) does not.

Any suggestions to why this doesn't work? You can inspect the HTML on my web page here: http://www.savedeth.com/parlours/

Comment: Firefox, safari, chrome.

Comment: Not really sure but you may find _[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261939/height-page-div-structure)_ question very helpful.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Screw it. Who doesn't have javascript anyways? Especially for this demographic.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
if($("body").height() < $(window).height()){
    $("body").height($(window).height());
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer at all the "why"

Comment: It's just not nice to use JavaScript. You said Screw it yourself, but this shouldn't be the defacto best way to do it. Don't like that it got a correct answer thingy.

Comment: Jquery is quite overkill.

Comment: I've never upvoted an answer for being funny instead of correct or practical until now. Great work!

Answer (score 37):

Specify `height: 100%` on the `html`, `body` and `#body2` elements (line 1358).

```
html, body, #body2
{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Not tested in IE 6, works in 7 though.

Comment: Yes, works on the home page, but no on the "media" page, or any page that expands past 100%.

Comment: Life saver, thank you!  I didn't even think to put 100% on the html element!?!

Comment: Here's another crazy fact for you, just tested in a minimal case on Chrome 30.0: If you create an empty page with just the above, then add a `div` using just `min-height: 100%`, that `div` will stretch just fine to the height of `body`. If you then add another `div` inside that first one, and try `min-height: 100%`, _it will not work_. You have to propagate `height:100%` down through every level that will contain child elements that are expected to stretch to 100% height (this being why the CSS style is applied to _both_ `html` and `body`), in this case meaning the `div` directly under `body`.

Answer (score 33):

Using vh instead of % worked for me without having to use any extra tricks.

This is what I have:

```
html, body, .wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Where .wrapper is the class you apply to your container/wrapper or main body of content that you wish to stretch the full length of the screen height.

This will work as you would expect it to when the content within the wrapper is less or more than the screen height allows.

This should work in [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: for me too... In my case the parent div had a min-height set as well, so min-height won't work on the child div, unless using 'vh' WEIRD.

Comment: note that 100vh doesn't take into account the scrollbar height if there's one

Answer (score 4):

You have your min-height set to 100% which will only be as tall as any elements that fill the space.  Express you min-height in terms of pixels.  Also, note that IE6- requires it's own set of rules.  See http://davidwalsh.name/cross-browser-css-min-height for more details.

Comment: But I set the HTML and BODY tag min-height to 100%, so that will (and it does, look at the gradient) fill the height of the window.

Comment: I think the affect your trying to achieve will be much easier if you place the background image on the HTML and BODY tag.  You won't have to specify any heights in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`position: absolute;` works in most cases. For example:

```
#body2 { 
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Complete Answer

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: calc(100vh - <margin-top + margin-bottom>px);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

something is setting the height of your body element to 320px (if you look in chrome's inspect element)

therefore 100% is of 320px. that is why is it only showing on the top of the page with 100% of 320 px height.

you have to set a height for the min-height to work.

so set the height @ 100% in general should work.

Comment: Not true. You can set HTML and body to min-height: 100% to fill the window. So if you set the next element to min-height:100% it should fill the parent element. Also the 320px is coming from the content, not any css. Chrome is showing you the "displayed" height, not the set height.

Comment: look at @micheal copeland. same reason. that is where the 320px is coming from -- biggest element

Comment: Maybe the better question is: How does the BODY's background fill the window when it's height is 320px. Do we trust the content, or the background?

Comment: well sinse you set min-height to 100% it goes by content