# My height for my page does not fill full height? How do I make it responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, height

My height isn't being responsive. I referenced this question:

[Why is min-height not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277161/why-is-min-height-not-working)

but it still isn't working. My site to reference is http://horsescowsandcemeteries.com/.

I want it to work for both desktop and mobile. Thanks.

Vh isn't working.

Comment: What exactly do you want scaled? The website already seems responsive.

Comment: you have to provide an example of your problem, because you certainly missed many points in you code. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "viewport" meta tag to scale your website similarly to the browser version. Simply place the code below into the `head` element.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And if you want to fix the `body` background when scaling, you can use this:

```css
body {
    height: fit-content;
}
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/427xH.png) / [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfFnl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to your HTML and add try this css

```
/*Game Play Screen */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url(images/road-bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Krona One";
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.team-one, .team-two {
  width: 50%;
}

#left-side,
#right-side {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#instructions {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 140%;
}

#instructionsButton {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.teamBox {
  color: white;
  background: #333;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 6px solid white;
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  margin: 5em auto;
}

.teamBox h3,
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#scoreTotalTeamOne,
#scoreTotalTeamTwo {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

#endButton {
  background-color: #be1e2d;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.gameplaybutton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

/* First breakpoint, elimates the road */
@media only screen and (max-width: 675px) {
  body {
    height: auto;
    background: url(images/road-bg-sm.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .teamBox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
 #instructionsButton{
   font-size: 1em;
 }
}

/* Second breakpoint */
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .gameplaybutton {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
}
```